# How to set the first child of `org.w3c.dom.element`?

Tags: java, dom, w3c

I have a rootelment `rootSVG` of 'org.w3c.dom.element' class and I have a method which takes the sets the name of the script depending on the condition ,and creates a scriptelement and uses appendchild to insert that scriptelement as a child node for the rootelement.It sets the attribute("onload")  of the root element and as this script.

But we know appendchild always inserts a node as the last child ,I want to know is there any mechanism that I can set this element as the first child node for the rootelement because in IE I get the message at times that the particular script is undefined when we load the page for the first time. Given below is the code snippet.

```
     if ( bEnableMouseEvents )
     {
        String scriptName = "SvgScriptUtils";            
        if ( !bUsingPlugin )
           scriptName = scriptName + "Native";
        // insert external javascript driver for tooltips/navigation-mode/popups            
        rootSVG.setAttribute("contentScriptType", "text/ecmascript");
        Element scriptElement = doc.createElementNS(SVGDOMImplementation.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI, SVGConstants.SVG_SCRIPT_TAG);
        scriptElement.setAttribute("type", "text/ecmascript");
        XlinkHref.set(scriptElement, "/scripts/" + scriptName + ".fs");
        rootSVG.appendChild(scriptElement);
        rootSVG.setAttribute("onload", scriptName + ".initMOS(evt)");           
     }
```

Answer (score 8):

Try `Node.insertBefore(Node newChild, Node refChild)` where `refChild` would be your currently first child (which, if you don't know it, you could get it by calling `Node.getFirstChild()` ).

For more information take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#insertBefore%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20org.w3c.dom.Node%29).